# Hide row / Activate formulas based on whether checkbox is "TRUE/FALSE"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm working on a spreadsheet for my car dealership business in an RP Game and I've got everything working how I want besides separating the "Fully Purchased" car sales and the "Financed" car sales.

I want it set up so when someone checks the box under the "Finance?" column, it calculates all of the formulas in the Finance Information table, otherwise, if the box is unchecked I want that particular row in the "Finance Information" table to be clear/hidden/£0 values.

[image]

above is an image with a brief annotation of what it looks like/how i want it to work.

I'm fairly new to sheets but I've learnt a lot in the past couple days I've been working on it. I've been messing around with =IF, =COUNTIF, =SUMIF, =SUMIFS, =QUERY and so on desperately trying to make something work to no avail.

Not sure if what I want to do is too farfetched for formulas and will require a script?

Thanks in advance

[EDIT 1]: The formula in the "Down Payment" Column is just =SUM(40%*F4)

Comment: Can you share a public link to a spreadsheet.  Make sure that you don't share any private information.

Comment: @Cooper https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ec8No7pzG2tVMrKge3xdpYjKOcbH0WPfCFprAfmUsc/edit?usp=sharing

let me know if you need edit permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the value of the check-box as "True" (checked) or "False" (unchecked) in an IF formula. From this [blog post](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-checkbox/) if you have the cell with the checkbox selected, you should see "True" or "False" in the formula bar.

So, I would recommend trying something like this in each of your "Finance Information" columns. Based on your edit, for the Down Payment in row 3:

```
=IF(H4, SUM(40%*F4), "")
```

Based on a comment, and further [reading](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7684717?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) it looks like you set up the checkbox through Data > Data Validation and assigned the True value to be "Owned". If this is the case, try:

```
=IF(H4="Owned", SUM(40%*F4), "")
```

This should test for the checked value.

Comment: This seems to be getting closer, I tried it and I ended up with an error expecting "boolean values" 

"Error
Function IF parameter 1 expects boolean values. But 'Owned' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean."

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ec8No7pzG2tVMrKge3xdpYjKOcbH0WPfCFprAfmUsc/edit?usp=sharing

incase you want to peruse

Comment: I updated the answer to make it more complete for your case, if I guessed correctly. Hope this does it for you!

Comment: This was perfect, thank you very much. I used your code and then altered a couple IF formulas for the other boxes and managed to get them all clear when the finance box is unticked and operate when ticked. Appreciate ya mate

Comment: Nice! TBH I'm pretty impressed at your dedication to seeing this up!

Comment: I appreciate that mate, it's a little in-depth for an RP server but it's all worth it in the end. The more immersive the experience the better at the end of the day :P and I'm learning A LOT of excel / random code at the same time so all good.